# Why doesn't $stdout puts work?

Tags: ruby, file-io, stdout

I can't seem to get the file output to work correctly:

```
record = File.open("/tmp/record", "w")

old_stdout = $stdout
$stdout = record
$stderr = $stdout

puts "This is a record"
z = 10/0
```

I can't seem to get the output to a file when I run it from command line or pry. Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? What you have there when I ran it from `irb`, Ruby version 2.0. I'm not familiar with `pry` so it may have a different behavior.

Comment: I'm running Ruby 2.0, pry is an irb alternative

Comment: Interesting. Well on Ruby 2.0 it worked for me in `irb`, exactly as you show it in your post. I'm running Fedora 18 Linux, so perhaps it's a system dependency.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is you are not closing your file stream.

It's important to do so because the File buffer might not have been flushed to the file itself. Because your code is generating an error with the zero-divison, Ruby might not have closed the file correctly too.

That said, your code could be written much more cleanly and Ruby-like, without subverting how `puts` can be used to write to a file:

```
File.open("/tmp/record", "w") do |record|
  record.puts "This is a record"
end
```

That will automatically close the file output when the block exits.

Perhaps you're trying to capture the output of the self-induced zero-division exception you're generating using `z = 10/0`?

You can do that by rescuing the exception; You can't get Ruby to continue running without that:

```
File.open("./record", "w") do |record|

  record.puts "This is a record"

  begin
    z = 10/0
  rescue Exception => e
    record.puts e.message
  end

end
```

After running, "record" contains:

```
This is a record
divided by 0
```

Alternatively, you could go about it this way:

```
File.open("./record", "w") do |record|

  old_stdout, old_stderr = $stdout, $old_stderr
  $stdout = $stderr = record

  puts "This is a record"

  begin
    z = 10/0
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
  end

  $stdout, $stderr = old_stdout, old_stderr
end
```

Which, after running, "record" again contains:

```
This is a record
divided by 0
```

There are times we want to play games by reassigning STDOUT and STDERR, but, in general, I'd recommend not doing that. Instead, directly write to them using things like:

```
$sterr.puts "foo blowed up"
```

This is to make it more obvious what is happening, for readability and maintainability. If you had redirected $stderr to a file, and it was 3:00AM and you're trying to remember what it is the code does because you have a system-down, and you're not seeing your output like you expect, you might be tempted to *rewrite* the code to be the above, or hack in something that forces the output where you expect. The confusion can cascade from there.